# The Warm Oven Temp. for Cakes

Tags: baking, oven, temperature

My Mom is making a cake. Its an old recipe, 50 - 70 yrs old (or older). All it says is to use a warm oven. No temperature range, just a warm oven. What temperature would this be?

Comment: Do you have any more information about the recipe? What are the ingredients?

Answer (score 2):

Without any details on the recipe, it is hard to offer any firm recommendations. That said, I have had success using a convection oven on 180 degrees Celsius (356 degrees Fahrenheit), and checking for doneness with a bamboo skewer.

Comment: I think any recipe old enough to only mention "warm oven" will not anticipate convection.

Comment: +1, I have yet to see a standard cake for which 180 convection is a bad temperature (there are pastries which need it hotter, but they are not usually called "cake").

Answer (score -2):

For some cakes, I bake longer at 300F, and the result is quite delicate.